# Conflict between components div background and actual background color

Tags: reactjs

I have a listview within a div that changes the background color based on day / night mode. The background in the index.html is set to white and is set to stretch to 100% of the height which works for day mode. The issue is in night mode when I add elements to the listview it eventually starts showing a white bar at the bottom that increases in size for every element I add. I'm assuming the 100% height the background is set for isn't dynamic which is causing the issue when I add items to the listview. Any ideas on how to work around this?

**How the div renders**

nightMode is a state that changes the color between white and black for night mode.

```
return (
    <div style={{height: '100%', padding: 50, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: nightMode.background}}>

<div style = {{paddingTop: 40}}>
  <List>
    {todos.map((value, index) => {
      return(
        <ListItem key={todos.id}> 
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              edge="start"
              checked={false}
              onChange={() => removeTodo(index)}
              tabIndex={-1}
              disableRipple
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText disableTypography style={{fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 35, color: nightMode.listText}} primary={value.text}/>
        </ListItem>
      );
    })}

    <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
      <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
        Task Finished!
      </Alert>
   </Snackbar>
 </List>
</div>
```

**Index.html that creates the background at 100% height**

```
<style>
   html,
   body,
   #root {
     height: 100%;
   }

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff; /**This section is causing the issue**/
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed:

```
#root {
 height: 100%;
}
```

and the color scaled for the whole page. Hopefully there are no issues with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

why not update body background-color;

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = nightMode.background;
return (<div></div>)
```

Comment: this is effecting the HTML document from within the js file?

Comment: useEffect(()=> {
    var prevColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor; 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = nightMode.background; 
    ()=> document.body.style.backgroundColor = prevColor; 
}, [nightMode.background])